# reading data from csv files in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to extract data from a dummy csv file to use inside tensorflow.
The dummy data only has 2 columns: X (single feature column) and Y (expected output).

```
X     Y 
11.0 13.0
23.0 33.3 
...  ...  and so on
```

Right now I am reading the data like so:

```
import pandas as pd

dummy_data = pd.read_csv("dummy_data.csv", sep=",")
inputX = dummy_data.loc[:, 'X'].values
np.reshape(inputX, [11, 1])
```

I am reshaping the numpy array because I need to do matrix multiplication later on with linear regression but I want to ask is that the correct way to extract a column from csv data? Is there a better way to directly extract the csv data to a tensor object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to reshape or use `.loc` or `.values`:

```
inputX = dummy_data[['X']]
```

(Mind the list of lists `[[]]`!)